# Incorrect number of rows in ngTable

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/98kvWKgzE8fwgsEjkQce?p=preview) I have an ngTable with pagination of 3 rows per page set with `{count: 3}` in `NgTableParams`. Instead, the table is displaying 4 rows per page. How to fix this?

HTML:

```
  <table ng-table-dynamic="tableParams with cols" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="col in cols" ng-style="{ 'color': col.color }">{{col.title}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
      <td ng-repeat="col in cols" ng-style="{ 'color': col.color }" >{{row[col.nm]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTable']);

app.controller('myCtl', function($scope,NgTableParams) {

      $scope.cols = [ 
        {nm:'uid', title:'User ID', color: 'blue'}, 
        {nm:'ugr', title: 'Group ID', color: 'red'} 
      ];


      $scope.data = [ 
        { uid: 'aaa',ugr: '222'},
        { uid: 'bbb', ugr: '111'},
        { uid: 'ccc',ugr: '222'},
        { uid: 'ddd', ugr: '111'}
      ];

      $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({count: 3}, 
                                   {dataset: $scope.data, counts: []});

});
```

Comment: Count is computed from `$scope.data`, if you want only three rows to display then remove 4th row from data, or you want pagination, then set page.rowCount to 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change your code like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
          <td ng-repeat="col in cols" ng-style="{ 'color': col.color }" >{{row[col.nm]}}</td>
        </tr>


$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({count: 3}, {data: $scope.data, counts: []});
```

The reason is:
1、about '$data', please see [What is '$data' in ngtable's HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29507706/what-is-data-in-ngtables-html-page)
2、about 'data' replace 'dataset', please see [Angular ng-table not loading dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34787456/angular-ng-table-not-loading-dataset)

Comment: I tried your solution and it didn't work, can you change my plunk and post it? By the way, the demos in ngTable website use `dataset`, not `data`.